# Program Blocked by Group Policy - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, executable, windows-7-x64, group-policy, settings

I am facing issue while running a EXE. I ahve tried all possible way avialble on net as far as I did research.

1) Go to gpedit.msc-computer configuration-windows settings-security settings-local policies-security options.Change "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for standard users:" to "prompt for credentials".

2) I tried keeping EXE entry in Applocker also and providing full access. Tried both path and Hash.

3) REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer\CodeIdentifiers\ /v DefaultLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00040000 /f

Tried even adding a new key name 0 under this. Which i checked somewhere for this issue.

4) User has full access on folder. I provided through admin user. and Everone also has full access to fodler and EXE.

EXE seems to working jsut fine with admin access.

Comment: Did you reboot the domain control and the box?  Reboot does magical things.

Comment: I tried rebooting machine sevral time but not domain control box and I don't have access for same.

Comment: Sounds very much like you are in fact being blocked by group policy, perhaps because it is denying standard users the right to elevate, or perhaps because a whitelist or blacklist is in place.  Note that changes to the local policy will be overridden by the domain policy.  Try removing the computer from the domain, or moving it to an OU where no group policy is applied.  If that resolves the problem, then you need to carefully examine the group policy that is in place.